# Retrieve browser width in Devexpress/Blazor without Javascript

Tags: blazor, devexpress

Is it somehow possible to retrieve the browser width using only Devexpress/Blazor without any Javascript code?

I'm also intrested in different solutions if there is no way to do that with Devexpress / Blazor but I can't use Javascript as this is my companies project and they don't want any custom js code.

Using DxWindow.width only returns the current Window width, but that might not be the browser width.

Comment: something like this ? https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorPro.BlazorSize